# "X does not support your locale" error when running keepass2

Tags: xorg, locale, keepass

I am trying to run a password manager (Keepass2) that *was* working alright yesterday, until I started trying to tweak it to use the system-wide shortcut keys for auto-typing.
I am working on Debian 10.

#### The Issue:

When running keepass from bash I get the error, and then have to ctrl+C to exit.

```
~$ keepass2
X does not support your locale
^C
```

My actual keepass executable is this:

```
$ cat $(which keepass2)
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/cli /usr/lib/keepass2/KeePass.exe "$@"
```

KeePass.exe is run using the following application (I have chained the symlinks to save space):

```
/usr/bin/cli -> /etc/alternatives/cli -> /usr/bin/mono -> /usr/bin/mono-sgen
```

#### System Details:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

$ uname -a
Linux ux410uq 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ locale
LANG=en_IL
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_IL"
LC_NUMERIC=en_IL
LC_TIME=en_IL
LC_COLLATE="en_IL"
LC_MONETARY=en_IL
LC_MESSAGES="en_IL"
LC_PAPER=en_IL
LC_NAME=en_IL
LC_ADDRESS=en_IL
LC_TELEPHONE=en_IL
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IL
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IL
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

#### My Attemtps:

The issue appears to have begun around installation of the following packages, whilst I was trying to setup keyboard shortcut integration with my OS. However, removal of them *didn't* revert the problem...

```
sudo apt install \
  xsel \
  xdotool \
  mono-complete \
  libcanberra-gtk-module \
  libcanberra-gtk3-module \
```

During troubleshooting (based off other search results online) I tried adjusting the value of $LANG in following manner, to no avail (KeePass' GUI never came up...):

```
$ echo $LANG
en_IL
$ export LANG=en_US
$ keepass2 

(process:18003): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:40:07.107: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

^C
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ keepass2 

^C
```

Please assist me in restoring stability to my KeePass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue myself! (:

**Solution approach:**

I ran keepass in verbose mode, hoping to see what step it hung/failed on:

```
mono --verbose /usr/lib/keepass2/KeePass.exe
```

The step is froze on was to do with a line I recognized from the configuration file (`~/.config/KeePass/KeePass.config.xml`), so I reviewed it.

**Cause:**

The configuration file `~/.config/KeePass/KeePass.config.xml` contained a syntax error in one of the XML tags: `<TrayIcon>>`

**Solution:**

Corrected the syntax error: `<TrayIcon>`

**Prevention/fix suggestion:**

During initialization, the configuration file's syntax should be checked before importing values. If formatting errors are found, an explicit message should be raised for the user.